# How can I post a message to event wall via Graph API as a specific user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api

Old API has this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/, which allows me to specify uid (who is author of the post) and target_id (whose wall it is).

I can't find anything like that in current Graph API. Both https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ give me only an option to decide which wall I am using, but not who is the author.

E.g. user changes his RSVP to event in my application SuperFooBar and I want to give him possibility to also specify a RSVP comment. I need to post this comment via PHP SDK to event's wall as it was him/her writing that manually. Only I can achieve is to post the comment to event's wall as SuperFooBar application :(

Could anyone help, please? Thanks!

UPDATE: Now, totally desperate, I have actually tried the deprecated REST API way to do it. And it's apparently not possible any more, at all. Even the old REST API raises following error: **#200, The user isn't allowed to post to this event's wall**.

Well, but the question is still relevant. Is it possible to do this somehow? Is it possible to gain permissions to do that?

Comment: The author of a post should be the current user of the app. Are you getting an `access_token` for the user when they authorize your app? You'll need that. Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for more on that.

Comment: @chesles I am using PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/. You think that could be the problem? Maybe when it performs POST request, it doesn't use access_token properly and it results in posting the message as app, not as the user. Thank you for suggestion, I'll explore this. PHP SDK can be buggy.

Comment: Maybe if you post a little code, we'll be better equipped to help you.